# onclick does not work reliably

Tags: html, onclick

I have the following [html](http://jsfiddle.net/gonvaled/wmcME/). It is a pager which triggers actions on the server side using buttons with icons. The icons have an `onclick` event attached which is supposed to trigger a server URL (in the `jsfiddle` I am simply triggering an `alert`), like this:

```
<button class="btn bootstrap-button-margin-style force-height" type="button">
 <i class="icon-step-forward" onclick="alert('step-forward');">
 </i>
</button>
```

If you click around, you will notice that the alerts are not always shown (I would say they are just shown 60% of the times - I am using Chrome).

- Why is that?
- Is there a way to make the `onclick` event reliable?
- Is there a better alternative to `onclick`, so that the icons are triggering the corresponding server action in a reliable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have attached the onclick event to the icon, not the buttons. The alert appears 100% of the time when you click on the actual icon. The alert will not appear if you click on the button outside of the icon element.

Move the onclick event to the button element:

```
<button class="btn bootstrap-button-margin-style force-height" type="button" onclick="alert('step-forward');">  
    <i class="icon-step-forward"></i>  
</button>
```

A better approach would be to decouple the JavaScript logic from your HTML markup. You can use a JavaScript selector to handle the click event in a separate JavaScript block.

```
<button id="btn-step-forward" class="btn">  
    <i class="icon-step-forward"></i>  
</button>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#btn-step-foward').click(function(e) { alert('step-forward'); });
```

Answer (score 5):

You're adding onclick even to **i tag** which is only a part of button

You should add event to button object like

```
<button class="btn bootstrap-button-margin-style force-height" type="button" onclick="alert('step-forward');">
    <i class="icon-step-forward" >
    </i>
</button>
```

Fiddle Example http://jsfiddle.net/utku/wmcME/3/

For alternative i suggest using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) for better javascript experience